# How do I check for increased connection?

Tags: jdbc

```
   <Resource
    name="jdbc/myoracle"
    auth="Container"
    type="javax.sql.DataSource"
    driverClassName="oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver"
    url="-------"
    username="----"
    password="-------"
    initialSize="1"
    maxTotal="10"
    maxIdle="10"
    minIdle="1"
    maxWaitMillis="5000" 
/>
```

I'm using the above code.

However, the figure does not increase beyond one connection.
Mobile, chrome, explorer The value does not change when connected in any environment.

Is one connection sufficient because database access has been terminated quickly?

It is possible by increasing initialSize value, but I want to see the increase due to actual connection.

Please teach me the way.